# output as format in C++

Tags: c++

I have a text file template.txt:

---

To:

|1| |2| |3|

|4|

|5|, |6| |7|

Dear |1| |3|:
You and the |3| family may be the lucky winner of $1,000,000 in the C++ programming competition!.....

---

and i have a text file database.txt:

---

Mr.|Harry|Morgan|1105 Main st|San Francisco|CA|95014|

Dr.|John|Lee|702 Ninth St Apt 4|San Jose|CA|95109|

Miss|Evelyn|Garcia|100 University Place|Ann Arbor|MI|48105|

---

my code can display the first line in database.txt as the format in template.txt correctly.

my output in the last.txt(created by myself) :

To:
Mr. Harry Morgan
1105 Main st
San Francisco, CA 95014
Dear Mr. Morgan:
You and the Morgan family may be the lucky winner of $1,000,000 in the C++ programming competition!.....

**I want to display the next two lines as the same format in last.txt as well.
I used while loop, even make a new function, it does not work at all.
Hope someone can help me! thanks!**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;


void edit(ifstream& data, ifstream& temp, ofstream& last)
{
    char x;
    char x2, x3;
    string arr[21];
    string line;


    for (int j = 1; j<21; j++)
    {
        getline(data, line, '|');
        arr[j] = line;
        cout << arr[j] << endl;
    }

    while (temp.get(x))
    {
        if ('|' == x)
        {
            temp.get(x2);
            if (isdigit(x2))
            {
                temp.get(x3);
                if ('|' == x3)
                {
                    int n = x2 - '0';
                    //n+=7;
                    last << arr[n];
                }
                else
                    temp.putback(x3);
            }
            else
                temp.putback(x2);
        }
        else
            last << x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ofstream last;
    ifstream temp;
    ifstream data;
    temp.open("template.txt");
    data.open("database.txt");
    last.open("last.txt", fstream::app);
    if (data.fail()) { return 0; }


    edit(data, temp, last);


    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Whilst this probably doesn't solve your problem this might be worth looking at (c-style output method) http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to reposition to the beginning of the template file after processing a line from the names file. You'll need to restructure your code to have two loops though.